# Zip directory and sub directories recursively specific file format and download

Tags: php, linux, zip

I have been using a PHP script for a while to download .jpg files from current directory. I was wondering if it is possible to download .jpgs from current and all sub-directories, prompt for download and delete the archive after download is finished?

**Here is my script (Currently this script does not delete archive after download):**

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$download = 'FileName.zip';
$zip->open($download, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $file) { /* Add appropriate path to read content of zip */
    $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = $download");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($download));
header("Location: $download");
?>
```

Comment: So add a `readfile('FileName.zip')` and a `unlink('FileName.zip)`

Comment: I used the code as: `readfile('FileName.zip')` and `unlink('FileName.zip')` I get 404 error.

I used it wihtout apostrophe: `readfile(FileName.zip)` and `unlink(FileName.zip)` ZIP file is created and downloaded but does not delete the file after download error_log: `PHP Warning:  unlink(FileNamezip): No such file or directory in /.../test.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  readfile(FileNamezip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /../test.php on line 14`